# Why are the Terminators dragging a turbofan jet engine?

Tags: terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

In Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles season 1 episode 6 (Dungeons & Dragons) in one scene in 2027 Derek Reese and other soldiers see Terminator robots dragging a huge turbofan jet engine in the night.

[image]

[image]

Why are these robots taking this jet engine and what is their purpose?

Comment: IIRC, in the Terminator movies the terminators possessed aircraft of sorts.  Sort of like hovering jets.  Those engines would be useful for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cross Site answer by Valorum at [**Science Fiction & Fantasy**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/137850/what-did-skynet-want-a-jet-engine-for/137851#137851) who said....

> I initially thought Skynet might be strapping them onto [Hunter-killers](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Hunter-Killer).
>
> [image]
>
> But on rewatching the episode a second time, I realised that we do actually see them again. Skynet has turned several of them upright in order to power its Time-Displacement Equipment (TDE).
>
> [image]
>
> With correct gearing, a 6000rpm jet engine converted into a makeshift electricity generator could easily produce between 250-300Kw. Six of them in series could generate in the order of 1-2 megawatts of power on demand. Not the most elegant of solutions (noisy, breakable), but then Skynet was getting pretty desperate by this point and evidently needed to build the TDE at short notice, unlike other timelines where it was able to custom-build and dedicate an entire  facility to the TDE chamber.